# Vba, only if blank, formula in cells to bottom of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below formula created, but it is not working properly. Some of the cells in column G have numbers, others do not. I just want this formula to appear in column G for the blank cells.

Column G = commission rate (on the raw data download, commission rates are only showing here if they are a static rate for the duration of contract)
Column V = date an agreement was signed
Column AA:AF = commission rates by year into agreement (AA = year 1, AB = year 2, so on)

What I am trying to do is add the correct variable commission rate to the same column the static commission rates are on.

```
Sub Clean_Data()
Dim y As Range
lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

Set X = Range("G3:G" & lr)
For Each y In X.Cells

    If y = "" Then
        y = Formula = "=IF(AND(((TODAY()-V3)/365)>=0,((TODAY()-V3)/365)<=1),AA3,IF(AND(((TODAY()-V3)/365)>1,((TODAY()-V3)/365)<=2),AB3,IF(AND(((TODAY()-V3)/365)>2,((TODAY()-V3)/365)<=3),AC3,IF(AND(((TODAY()-V3)/365)>3,((TODAY()-V3)/365)<=4),AD3,IF(AND(((TODAY()-V3)/365)>4,((TODAY()-V3)/365)<=5),AE3,AF3)))))"
    End If
    
Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: `y = Formula = ` looks a bit off. Is that what you have actually written?

Comment: Hi BigBen, yes, but I am also a beginner with VBA. So any assistance on fixing this would be appreciated!

Comment: yeah `y.formula =` is what you're looking for. though i think that will only get you 1 step closer, try it and let us know

Comment: @user1236777, that was a good start. With my original code it was returning "False". Now it is returning the formula. It just isn't updating based on each row. So on row 4 down, it still lists V3, AA3 and so on.

Comment: yeah.  thats why i thought it was step one.  go look up R1C1 formula and then you'll need `y.formulaR1C1 =` and you'll have to change all of those references to V3 etc. to R1C1 format.  the R1C1 format is a relative format (i.e. RxCy is x cells down and y cells to the right of the current cell.  i think thats your best bet

Comment: `y.Formula = "=IF...."` You are missing the = sign at the start of your formula, so it's entering it as text instead of as a formula

Comment: Thank you Tigeravatar, noticed that as soon as it was posted, and has been corrected.

Comment: user1236777, R1C1 formula worked! Thank you to everyone for their input as well. Case closed.